# Generate a multi-dimensional array using x_axis and y_axis

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
var axis_x = document.getElementById("x_axis").value; // 3
var axis_y = document.getElementById("y_axis").value; // 2

for (var i=1; i <= axis_x; i++){
    axs_x.push(i); // [1,2,3]
    alert(axs_x);
}
for(var j=1 ; j <= axis_y; j++){
    axs_y.push(j); // [1,2]
    alert(axs_y);
}
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue. The actual result I need is:

```
[11, 12, 21, 22, 31, 32]
```

Comment: What is the issue? Please tell us what is happening, what is going wrong and where in the code it happens. (What output are you getting right now instead of the desired output?) Right now this question is too unclear for us to understand what you are asking.

Comment: What is this: `axs_y.push(j);[1,2]` suppose to mean/do?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you looking to get output [11,12,21,22,31,32] or [ [11,12],[21,22],[31,32]] or possibly [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2],[3,1],[3,2]]?

Comment: I need the first output [11,12,21,22,31,32]

Comment: axs_x.push(i);    //[1,2,3] - example

Comment: @IrasaKumar, if you find a working/proper example for your question, please accept it and/or upvote it accordingly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need **to generate x/y-axis couples** given by the value (innerHTML) of 2 divs, **try this out:**

```js
function getAxisNum(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  
  if (elem) {    
    return parseInt(elem.innerHTML, 10);
  }
  
  return null;
}

function generate(x, y) {
  var arr = [];  
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= y; j++) {
      arr.push(i * 10 + j)
    }    
  }
  
  return arr;
}

var axis_x = getAxisNum('x_axis');
var axis_y = getAxisNum('y_axis');

alert(generate(axis_x, axis_y)); // [11, 12, 21, 22, 31, 32]
console.log(generate(axis_x, axis_y)); // [11, 12, 21, 22, 31, 32]
```

```html
<div id="x_axis">3</div>
<div id="y_axis">2</div>
```

Comment: This does what is asked, but you could just use a simpler outer loop for (var i = 1, i<=x; i++) , and then push(i*10+j) in the inner loop

Comment: @visibleman, yes, you are correct! I fixed it. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: can i know why you stated value 10?

Comment: The number 10 comes from your question and what output you need.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly this is what you want

```
var axis_x = document.getElementById("x_axis").value;//3
var axis_y = document.getElementById("y_axis").value;//2

for (var i=1; i <= axis_x; i++){
    for(var j=1 ; j <= axis_y; j++){
        alert(axs_x);
        alert(axs_y);
    }
}
```